# Database table keeps reverting back to former state (MySQL AWS RDS)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, typeorm, database-migration

I've been observing some weird behaviour in my database tables for some weeks now. I'm using NodeJS + Typescript along with a MySQL DB (on AWS RDS) + TypeORM. In my data-source.ts file `synchronize` was set to `true` during development. Before we moved to production I obviously set it to `false`. With time we had to update the database table so I resorted to running migrations for that using the TypeORM CLI migration commands. The migrations work and are applied. But after some weeks, it seems the migrations revert or something, because the added columns will no longer be found in the database table when I check and I'd keep getting this error:
`"Unknown column 'Vehicle.vehicleNumber' in 'field list'"` with the `vehicleNumber` column being the column that was just added in the migration. It also happens to other columns as well. I'd now have to rerun the migration again (obviously I have to alter something in the table to create a new migration otherwise TypeORM and MYSQL won't pickup the new migration). I do this every few several weeks and its frustrating.

Here are my schemas:

**Vehicle Entity:**

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Vehicle {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column()
  vehicleNumber: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  type: string;

  @Column({ type: Number })
  basePrice: number;

  @Column()
  pickupDuration: number; // In days

  @Column()
  deliveryDuration: number; // In days

  @Column()
  capacity: number;

  @Column()
  location: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  available: boolean;

  @Column()
  ownerID: string;

  @Column()
  image: string;

  @Column()
  riderName: string;

  @Column()
  riderPhoneNumber: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

**Delivery Entity:**

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  ValueTransformer,
} from "typeorm";
import { Point } from "geojson";
import { PaymentStatus, Status } from "../../utils/enums";

// For location data
const pointTransformer: ValueTransformer = {
  to: (value: Point | null) => (value ? JSON.stringify(value) : null),
  from: (value: string | null) => (value ? JSON.parse(value) : null),
};

@Entity()
export class Delivery {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column("uuid")
  senderID: string;

  @Column()
  receiverPhoneNumber: string;

  @Column()
  pickupAddress: string; // | Array<number>; // Could be string addr or coordinates

  @Column()
  pickupName: string;

  @Column()
  pickupPhoneNumber: string;

  @Column()
  pickupCoordinates: string;

  @Column()
  deliveryAddress: string; // | Array<number>;

  @Column()
  deliveryCoordinates: string;

  @Column({ type: "enum", enum: Status, default: "pending" })
  status: Status;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  logisticsCompanyID: string;

  @Column({ type: Number, nullable: true })
  rating: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  review: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  reviewDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  vehicleID: string;

  @Column({
    type: "text",
    nullable: true,
    transformer: pointTransformer,
  })
  dispatchRiderCurrentLocation: Point; //Array<Array<[number, number]>>; // [[lat, lon], [lat, lon], [lat, lon]...];j

  @Column()
  cost: number;

  @Column()
  packageWeight: number;

  @Column()
  paymentMethod: string;

  @Column({ default: PaymentStatus.Unpaid })
  paymentStatus: PaymentStatus;

  @Column()
  receiverName: string;

  @Column()
  receiverEmail: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  pickupTime: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true, default: "No notes" })
  notes: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

We're not really into like main main production, though, so I had to set `synchronize` to `true` again in my data-source to fix the issue then turned it back off (`false`) after restarting the local server, but today, after some weeks again I observed the same behaviour again. Also, having `synchronize` set to `true` seemed to clear some of my data because some columns (especially the new columns from the recent migrations) become completely empty, so I don't want to do that again.

Also, if its of any importance we're using AWS Free tier